# Tool Tip Won't Display Metrics Tableau

Tags: tooltip, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Does anyone have any idea why my tool tip won't display the metrics selected?  I learning Tableau and have never had this happen.

I was trying to calculate top sales usiing a calculated field that I created. If I use any other metric the toll tip will display.  The tool tip appears to not like the calculated field I created, but the calculated feild gives the most accurate figure for sales.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little tricky in Tableau. you need to drag your Calculated field in the tooltip box (highlighted in yellow) and click on it. there you can edit the options. Hope that helps

[image]